# Normalized autocorrelation of a sum of two signals

Tags: continuous-signals, autocorrelation

I obtained the autocorrelation function of a sum of two signals:
[image]
as
[image]

but I want to know what is the normalized autocorrelation of above equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a scaled autocorrelation such that its maximum value, hopefully attained at $\tau=0$, has value $1$.

Comment: You probably meant to write $\tau = 0$. It is too small an edit for me to make the change myself..

Comment: With very high probability

Comment: Thanks for your response . It means this http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/5717394800_1470977553.png ?

Comment: If you are certain about your $R_x(\tau)$ (you ought to mark its dependency on $\tau$), yes